# How to use Firebase Authentication and Firebase Admin properly?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a small lightweight app (node.js, express, socket.io, handlebars) and I need to have users (<5) authenticated backend as well, I'm using firebase auth (client-side) and firebase admin (server-side) and I know how to get the token and check it, etc.. this isn't about that.

I don't really understand the big picture in terms of Firebase Authentication and Firebase Admin relationship.

So is it okay to code it this way:

Client:

**[Client-side]** User signs in with Firebase Authentication (this is front end only)

> Client makes a request -> send IdToken -> server verifies IdToken -> sends
>   back requested data or does some action.

So do I verify IdToken on every request, or try to manage login state on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application server code typically has no business understanding the sign on state of the user on the front end.  The Firebase Auth SDK on the client that handles that detail.  It's the ID token, managed by the SDK, that validates that a user is currently authenticated, so that should be sent with every request that requires auth.

Comment: Thanks just what I needed to know.